# Where to ask questions about companies' policies on sharing information regarding health plans?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where to ask questions about companies' policies on sharing information regarding health plans?

Example:

> Title: Why do some companies in the United States ask their employees not to share information regarding health plans?
>
> Body: Why do some companies in the United States ask their employees not to
> share information regarding health plans? I.e.,  why do some companies
> keep information regarding health plans confidential, accessible to
> the company employees only?
>
> I'm surprised as typically company benefits are publicly
> accessible/advertised.

A moderator on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ told me it is off topic there.

Comment: Are you sure this is a widespread thing? If this is specific to one, or a very few companies in the US then there probably isn't a suitable site.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have no idea, but given the large size of the company where I saw this happening I would guess, perhaps incorrectly, that it is not such a rare case.  I also don't seem to easily find healh care plans from random company via Google. A interesting follow-up question would indeed be how common it is.

Answer (score 7):

A health plan question about [one specific company is off-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96136/70590) at **Workplace.SE** but general questions about health plans, even [the difference between two at one company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/86172/70590) are on-topic; the second link *might* answer your question.